# Using xcopy in a batch file with %programfiles%

Tags: dos, xcopy

I'm trying to use a batch file to help setup a build project.
As part of that process I need to copy a lot of files from a temporary directory:
%temp%\wcu to a new directory in the %programfiles% directory.

I am using the following command:

```
xcopy %temp%\wcu\dotnetframework\*.* %programfiles%\"Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35SP1" /S
```

Of course the problem is that %programfiles% equates to "C:\Program Files" with a space and so xcopy throws a wobbly.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use quotes

```
xcopy "%temp%\wcu\dotnetframework\*.*" "%programfiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35SP1" /S
```

Comment: Actually this one seems to work, which surprised me as I would have thought that the quote marks would have overridden the % sign.